# predicate that store best solution of comparison

Tags: prolog

i try to write a code that find the best goal that meets my condition

```
point(1,2).
point(1,10).
point(2,3).
point(5,2).
point(4,4). 

best(X, GT, Goal) :- 
    once(Goal),
    assert(val(X)),
    fail 
;
    Goal,
    once(retract(val(Y))),
    keep_greater(GT,X,Y),
    fail
;
    retract(val(X)).

keep_greater(GT,X,Y) :-
    GT(X,Y), !,
    assert(val(X))
;   assert(val(Y)), !.

once(Goal) :- Goal, !.
```

examples:

```
best(Y,>,point(_,Y)).  => Y = 10 
best(X,>,point(X,_)).  =>  X = 5
best(X,<,point(X,_)). => X = 1
```

cant figure out why its not working the code is always crash after keep greater rule.
thanks for your help.

Comment: Why are you redefining `once/1`? It's already defined, properly, in SWI Prolog.

Comment: Are your examples what you want or what you're getting? Please be clear about that. Show what you're getting if they're what you want, and vice versa. Also, why are you using `assert` and `retract` to solve the problem?

Comment: by mistake it should be quoted write it for learning purpose.

Comment: my examples are what i want and what i got is an error.

Comment: What was the error that you saw?

Comment: line 20 syntax error 
GT(X,Y),!...

Comment: Try `call(GT, X, Y)`. In Prolog, `GT(X,Y)` is indeed a syntax error. Prolog thinks you're using a term that has a functor starting with a capital letter, which is not allowed.

Comment: @lurker: in case you need a functor starting with a capital letter, for instance for a DSL where such feature is important, there is an option in SWI-Prolog